# Prove limit of $n^2/n!$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was trying to prove that the limit of $\frac{n^2}{n!}=0$.

I started by noting that $n!\geq n (n-1) $ then
$$\frac{n^2}{n!} \leq \frac {n^2}{n (n-1)} $$ $$ =\frac {n}{n-1}$$ $$\leq \frac{n}{n/2}=2$$
Which I don't understand.  I figured out another way to prove it but I still don't know what went wrong with the proof here.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? You showed that the limit (if it exists) must be at most $2$.

Comment: Try repeating this with $n! \geq n (n-1) (n-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$n! \geq n(n-1)(n-2) = n^3 + O(n^2) \ $ for $ \ n\geq3$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n^2}{n(n-1)}\frac1{(n-2)!}.$$

The first ratio tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{n^2}{n!} = \dfrac{n}{(n-1)!} =$

$ \dfrac{1}{(n-2)!} +\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!} \lt $

$\dfrac{2}{(n-2)!} \lt \dfrac{2}{n-2} \lt $

$\dfrac{2}{n/2} = \dfrac{4}{n}.$

Let  $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Let $M \gt (4/\epsilon)$, and  $n_0 \gt M.$

For $n \ge n_0 $ we have:

$\dfrac{n^2}{n!} \lt \dfrac{4}{n} \lt$ $ \dfrac{4}{M} \lt \epsilon$.

Used: $n/2 \lt n-2$, I.e.   $n>4.$

Answer (score 0):

You're squeezing between $0$ and $2$, so you cannot conclude.

Rather, consider, for $n>2$,
$$
0\le\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n^2}{n(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!}\le\frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)}
=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{n})(n-2)}
$$
Squeezing goes well, this time.